# I can't seem to use SUM(*) and MAX(*) in the same query

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is have essentially a 3 column table based off two columns.

```
id, value
----------  
1,  7
1,  1 
2,  6 
3,  9
3,  2
4,  2
```

I want [below] from [above]...

```
 id, sum_of_strength, max_of_strength
 ---------------------------------------
  1, 8,               11
  2, 6,               11 
  3, 11,              11
  4, 2,               11
```

Here's what I'm playing around with currently, but the `max_value` is the same as the `sum_value`... Does anyone know if there's a way to do this. I've tried loads of other solutions but nothing has worked.

```
SELECT 
    sum_table.id,
    sum_table.sum_value,
    (SELECT MAX(sum_table.sum_value) AS max_value) AS max_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        original_table.id,
        CAST(SUM(original_table.value) AS UNSIGNED) AS sum_value
    FROM original_table
    GROUP BY original_table.id
) AS sum_table
GROUP BY sum_table.id;
```

Comment: Show a more clearer result you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the max value:

```
SELECT id,
       CAST(SUM(value) AS UNSIGNED) AS sum_value,
       (SELECT CAST(SUM(value) AS UNSIGNED) AS s
        FROM original_table
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY s DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS max_value
FROM original_table
GROUP BY id
```

Grouping has to be applied twice:

- The main query uses it to get the sum of `value` per `id`
- The subquery uses it to get the maximum sum among all ids

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/873870/2)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. You got it spot on... I was missing that `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can't wait for MySQL to get windowed / analytic functions :)

Comment: Actually, one last question if I may... let's say that `original_table` has a conditional clause, would I have to put it both in the sub-query and the outer-query or is there a trick to where I only have to put it in once?

Comment: @JohnCullen If you want to get the max value for the filtered result set, then yes you have to put it on both.

Comment: Great, that's not the biggest deal. Thank you so much.